# How to convert a date/time object into a decimal?

Tags: r, datetime

I have an object in R that I have converted to a POSIXct object:

```
data<- data.frame(date_time= c('2021-06-24 18:37:00', '2021-06-24 19:07:00', '2021-06-24 19:37:00', '2021-06-24 20:07:00','2021-06-24 20:37:00'))

data$date_time<- as.POSIXct(data$date_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I want to convert this column to a decimal that gets bigger as the time passes. For example, '2021-06-24 18:37:00' should be smaller than '2021-06-24 19:07:00' and so on. However everything that I have tried so far does yield a decimal, but it does not get bigger as the time goes on. I have tried this:

`data$date_time2<- yday(data$date_time) + hour(data$date_time)/24 + minute(data$date_time)/60`

However this yields:

```
[1] 176.3667 175.9083 176.4083 175.9500 176.4500
```

I need the numbers to increase incrementally as minutes go by. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A datetime object is an integer counting the number of seconds from 1/1/1970.  So this works `as.integer(data$date_time)` to create an integer value.  Note the datetime is reference to GMT timezone.
To get the date as a decimal, requires the use of some integer math.  The end result is the number of days from 1/1/1970 and the time as fraction.

```
data<- data.frame(date_time= c('2021-06-24 18:37:00', '2021-06-24 19:07:00', '2021-06-24 19:37:00', '2021-06-24 20:07:00','2021-06-24 20:37:00'))

data$date_time<- as.POSIXct(data$date_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")

intvalue <- as.integer(data$date_time)

#numbers of seconds, take the MOD with the seconds per day
#divide the result by seconds per day to make the decimal part
decfraction <- intvalue%%(3600*24)/(3600*24)

#perform integer division to get the number of days 
days <- intvalue%/%(3600*24)
# or as.integer(as.Date(data$date_time))

#put together for the final answer
dateAsDecimal <- days + decfraction

#result
#18802.78 18802.80 18802.82 18802.84 18802.86
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned that the number mapped to preserves order then `xtfrm` will map objects to order preserving numbers.  In the case of POSIXct objects it just returns the internal numeric representation, i.e. seconds since the UNIX Epoch.

```
xtfrm(data$date_time)
```